# Whitespace in search string when matching using grep.

Tags: grep

I have a file which looks like this.

```
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-ASN-A-206 0.616667 0.094872
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-GLU-A-31- 0.363077 0.151282
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-GLY-A-207 0.602564 0.060256
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-LEU-A-132 0.378151 0.288462
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-LEU-A-60- 0.376812 0.133333
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-GLU-A-2-z 0.333333 0.065385
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-SER-A-15- 0.400000 0.053846
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-GLU-A-2-z 0.333333 0.065385
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-SER-A-15- 0.400000 0.053846
17gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-SER-A-77- 0.415789 0.101282
15gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-VAL-A-47- 0.413793 0.215385
```

I want to grep out the lines that match a pattern [inclusive of the whitespace in it]. Let's say the pattern is: '10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-'

When I give such a  pattern as an argument to grep, I get the matching lines correctly. However the problem arises when I want to match multiple patterns like these from a file say `pattern.txt` which has a list of all these patterns on each line.

`pattern.txt` looks like this:

10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-

10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-

When I use a shell script like this:

```
for i in `cat pattern.txt`; do grep -e "^$i" bigfile.txt ; done
```

the command takes `10gs+VWW+A+210` separately and 11ba separately to match. I want to match the entire thing (separated by a space) i.e. 10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba to be matched, and not the two strings separately.

How do I modify the existing shell script to overcome the white space character in the search string?

Also, since the file against which I am matching these set of strings is large, ~50GB.
So, a memory efficient solution is welcome. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace spaces with other symbols**

Assuming `#` never occurs in the patterns

```
 for i in $( cat pattern.txt | tr ' ' '#' ) ; do 
            j=$(echo "$i" | tr '#' ' ' ) 
            grep -e "^$j" bigfile.txt 
 done
```

Timing on my test file

```
real    0m20.739s
user    0m11.773s
sys     0m8.345s
```

**Use -f flag in grep**

```
 grep -f pattern.txt bigfile.txt
```

Timing on the same test file

```
real    0m2.190s
user    0m2.163s
sys     0m0.026s
```

In other words, the performance of `grep -f` appears to be about 10 times better with a large pattern file.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following command and corresponding result suit you? The patterns must be split by a pipe to make either one of them match.

Command:

```
egrep '10gs\+VWW\+A\+210 11ba-|10gs\+VWW\+A\+210 10gs-' bigfile.txt
```

Result:

```
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-ASN-A-206 0.616667 0.094872
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-GLU-A-31- 0.363077 0.151282
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-GLY-A-207 0.602564 0.060256
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-LEU-A-132 0.378151 0.288462
10gs+VWW+A+210 10gs-LEU-A-60- 0.376812 0.133333
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-GLU-A-2-z 0.333333 0.065385
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-SER-A-15- 0.400000 0.053846
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-GLU-A-2-z 0.333333 0.065385
10gs+VWW+A+210 11ba-SER-A-15- 0.400000 0.053846
```